# Set mapbox viewport to center of 2 markers

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

How to set center of the map to center of the two markers, `markerStart` and `markerEnd` in my case.

I tried using `center={[lat,lng]}` as prop but nothing works.

It seems there must be a prop to do so, but the docs are so wide. All I see is `fitBounds` and `center` but somehow they are not working as a prop to `ReactMapGL`

```
<ReactMapGL
   {...mapViewPort} // contains latitude and longitude
   preventStyleDiffing={false}
   width={width}
   height={height || 300}
   mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9"
   mapboxApiAccessToken={mapboxApiAccessToken}
   onViewportChange={(newViewPort) => viewportChangeHandler(newViewPort)}
   // center={[32.958984, -5.353521]}
   // fitBounds={[[32.958984, -5.353521], [43.50585, 5.615985]]}
>

   { markerStart.latitude &&
     <Marker
       longitude={markerStart.longitude}
       latitude={markerStart.latitude}
     >
       <Pin size={30} pinColor='#d00' />
     </Marker>
   }
   { markerEnd.latitude &&
     <Marker
       longitude={markerEnd.longitude}
       latitude={markerEnd.latitude}
     >
       <Pin size={30} pinColor='#323844' />
     </Marker>
   }
</ReactMapGL>
```

Comment: Did you try using the `latitude`/`longitude` props (instead of center)?

Comment: @MeltedPenguin latitude/longitude will work, but then I'll have to calculate the latitude/longitude of center point myself. I don't think its the best approach as this would not scale i.e. if points increases from 2 to 3 and so on